# Rethinkdb is getting down

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I am working on rethink db. I was running fine until now. It is getting down when i query some data. In Cluster performance it reading 30k reads/sec. What to do ?
I am sharing screenshot of my rethinkdb configuration [image]

Anybody expert in RethinkDB. Please help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: you mean your database instance is shutting down? if so, i had same problems when database runs out of memory. Can you share your `df -h` from server and also `htop` from your server? That 30k reads are normal, depending of course on your database size.